# Rails admin and pundit - Ensure only admins can see admin dashboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin, pundit

I'm using the gem `rails admin` and `pundit`. I'm trying to ensure that only `admin users` can see the admin dashboard, but I've never used pundit before. I feel as though this must be a well documented answer but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for so hopefully some can help me here. Here is my code:

### Routes:

```
mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', as: 'rails_admin'
```

I have that in my routes.rb file, But right now every user has access to it how can I wrap it in a condition checking for if the user is an admin? Like I said I have an `admin` boolean on `user`. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify [request based constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints) to specify the guard conditions.